# How to prevent logging USER_AUTH and USER_LOGIN events with auditd

Tags: auditd

I am trying to log changes to a file system using auditd, but I am seeing also many other things being logged, for example all failed SSH logging attempts (USER_AUTH and USER_LOGIN events). How can I prevent them from being logged? When I do `auditctl -l` I see only the path watching rules and no other rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things you **don't** want in the audit logs, you can add them to an exclude filter. So if you want to exclude logins, you can do

```
[root@finch jenny]# auditctl -a exclude,never -F msgtype=USER_AUTH
[root@finch jenny]# auditctl -a exclude,never -F msgtype=LOGIN
```

will stop logging of all logins, successful or not. For more information about how to create these rules, see the man page for auditctl.

However, you might simply use `aureport` to search for the logs you do want, instead of blocking the ones you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find these events coming out of the pam system. Perhaps there is an option in pam that prevents it from auditing.